# Combining data.tables in R

Tags: r, data.table

I want to know how to combine data.tables in R. I need this for a machine learning project, I just made it a little bit easier. We predicted occupation codes using machine learning and now want to combine the predicted codes with codes of occupations that are similar to those predicted not in terms of wording but in terms of similiarity of occupational activity to increase accuracy those codes that will be later used in the interview

I have the following Code as an example:

```
id<-rep(c(1:4), each=25)

name<-rep(c("Hans", "Peter", "Klaus", "Florian"), each=25)

table<- data.table(ID=id, NAME=name)

id1<-c(1,1,1,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6)

name1<-c("Hans", "Hans", "Hans", "Peter", "Klaus", "Klaus", "Florian", "Florian", "Florian", "Helmut", "Helmut", "Helmut", "Helmut", "Karl", "Karl")

refid<-6+c(seq(1:15))

refname<-c("Claudia","Julia", "Sophie","Lara","Lea","Sarah","Marie","Lena","Leonie","Anna","Jana","Maria","Susanne","Merle","Simone")

reftable<-data.table(ID=id1, NAME=name1, REFID=refid,REFNAME=refname)
```

So, I want to create a new table, where I list all 4 male names from table as unique values and then I want to create multiple columns, each containing one female name from the reftable (excluding those names from reftable that don't appear in table).

Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
uniquetqble <- data.table(NAME = unique(table$NAME))
mergetable <- reftable[uniquetqble, on = "NAME"]
   ID    NAME REFID REFNAME
1:  1    Hans     7 Claudia
2:  1    Hans     8   Julia
3:  1    Hans     9  Sophie
4:  2   Peter    10    Lara
5:  3   Klaus    11     Lea
6:  3   Klaus    12   Sarah
7:  4 Florian    13   Marie
8:  4 Florian    14    Lena
9:  4 Florian    15  Leonie
```

The idea is to merge first

```
dcast(mergetable,NAME ~ REFNAME)
      NAME Claudia Julia Lara Lea Lena Leonie Marie Sarah Sophie
1: Florian      NA    NA   NA  NA Lena Leonie Marie    NA     NA
2:    Hans Claudia Julia   NA  NA   NA     NA    NA    NA Sophie
3:   Klaus      NA    NA   NA Lea   NA     NA    NA Sarah     NA
4:   Peter      NA    NA Lara  NA   NA     NA    NA    NA     NA
```

, and then transform the data in the large (or broad) format to have a column per girl name

Comment: A more concise version is `dcast(reftable[table[, .(ID = unique(ID))], on = .(ID)], NAME ~ REFNAME)`

Comment: @Uwe thanks. but it is less understandable for most of us :)